# using Julius outside Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-julius

I am trying to figure out how to emit Javascript code using standalone Julius outside yesod:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as LazyIO
import Text.Julius

main = do
    let delta = 1 :: Int
    LazyIO.putStrLn $ renderJavascript $ [julius|
        function f(x) {
          return x + #{delta};
        }
    |] undefined
```

But I am getting this error:

```
t2.hs:8:48:
    No instance for (ToJavascript Integer)
      arising from a use of ‘toJavascript’
    In the expression: toJavascript delta
    ...
```

Please help. I have no idea what it needs, I have just started looking at Julius. If I remove the interpolation then it renders the text successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as LazyIO
import Text.Julius
import Data.Aeson

main = do
    let delta = toJSON (1 :: Int)
    LazyIO.putStrLn $ renderJavascript $ [julius|
        function f(x) {
          return x + #{delta};
        }
    |] undefined
```

Explanation:

The error message is saying that `delta` needs to have a `ToJavascript` instance. Looking up the `ToJavascript` class shows that these instances are defined by default:

```
ToJavascript Bool    
ToJavascript Value   
ToJavascript RawJavascript
```

The lack of an `Int` (or `Integer`) instance explains the error message.

However, there is a `Value` instance, and by using `toJSON` from the Aeson library we can turn an `Int` into a `Value`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `rawJS` should make it work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as LazyIO
import Text.Julius

main = do
    let delta = rawJS $ show (1 :: Int)
    LazyIO.putStrLn $ renderJavascript $ [julius|
        function f(x) {
          return x + #{delta};
        }
    |] undefined
```

Will produce:

```
function f(x) {
  return x + 1       
}
```